# different monitor for my laptop

Tags: laptop, external-display, acer-aspire-one

How can I use an external monitor on my Acer One laptop?  I dont really care about having an extra monitor, I just want to be able to hook up an external one at times to have a larger screen to work on.  Can I do this and have what is on my laptop screen show up on the external screen?

Answer (score 2):

The Acer Aspire One has a VGA out connection.

To find out how to set what is displayed on the external monitor, please consult the manual.

Comment: Thank you, I should have checked that first -- stupid me

Comment: I guess the obvious sometimes eludes me

Comment: @Brian: if this is the right answer (which it looks like it is to me), click the "accept" button.